# Laravel paginate ordering by 2nd table

Tags: laravel, sorting, pagination

So I need here some help. I am saving every user once to the dblog_steamusers table. For every Kill it saves the data as one whole row to the dblog_deaths table.

I want to get every user from dblog_steamusers and order them in a descending order by the amount of kills the user did. I also want to paginate the data from dblog_steamusers.

My question here is: How can I order the users by the kills they did in a descending order and also use the paginate() build in laravel.

My Controller:

```
public function informations()
{
    $users = SteamUsers::paginate();
    $wounds = Wounds::get();
    $deaths = Deaths::get();
    $revives = Revives::get();

    $informations = [
        $users,
        $wounds,
        $deaths,
        $revives
    ];

    return $informations;
}
```

[dblog_steamusers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHU1H.png)

[dblog_deaths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB9bR.png)

Maybe there is an other method working better. I am using laravel v10

Answer (score 1):

First of all use laravel documentaion. Very good.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination

Example:

```
public function informations()
{
    $users = SteamUsers::orderBy('kills', 'desc')->paginate(10); // Change 'kills' to your actual column name for kills

    $wounds = Wounds::get();
    $deaths = Deaths::get();
    $revives = Revives::get();

    $informations = [
        $users,
        $wounds,
        $deaths,
        $revives
    ];

    return $informations;
}
```

In this example, we're using the orderBy method to order the users by the 'kills' column in descending order. You should replace 'kills' with the actual column name representing kills in your dblog_steamusers table.

We also use the paginate(10) method to paginate the results, with each page containing 10 records. You can adjust the number 10 to your preferred page size.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries
Example kills other table:

```
public function informations()
{
    $users = SteamUsers::join('dblog_deaths', 'dblog_steamusers.steamID', '=', 'dblog_deaths.steamID')
        ->select('dblog_steamusers.*', DB::raw('COUNT(dblog_deaths.id) as kills'))
        ->groupBy('dblog_steamusers.steamID')
        ->orderBy('kills', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);

    $wounds = Wounds::get();
    $deaths = Deaths::get();
    $revives = Revives::get();

    $informations = [
        $users,
        $wounds,
        $deaths,
        $revives
    ];

    return $informations;
}
```

In this modified query, we use a join to connect the 'dblog_deaths' table, then use COUNT to count the total kills by users. We group by 'user_id' and order the results by kills in descending order. Finally, we paginate the results with 10 users per page.

Make sure to replace the table and column names with your actual database names in your Laravel application.